# http(s) DELETE and PUT methods in Youtube

Tags: http

Trying to understand the basics of `HTTP(S)` but confused.

I've made some comments in videos, edit and remove them as well as remove a couple of my own videos.

All I've seen in the network tab is `GET` and `POST` methods, shouldn't edits be `PUT` method and delete be `DELETE` method?

Comment: _shouldn't edits be PUT method and delete be DELETE method_ Yes it should

Comment: o_0 the question is exactly why that isn't the behavior seen in the console  @B001ᛦ